# curl fails on server with SSL proxy enabled

Tags: ssl, curl, https, proxy

I have been using a curl command to get data from squareup.com:

```
curl -s -H "authorization: Bearer "xyz" https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me
```

This had been working correctly until last week, when it started to fail.

In working with my hosting company, it turns out they made a server change and had SSL proxy enabled on the server. Now when it runs I get the following error:

```
== Info: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104
== Info: Closing connection 0.
```

My curl is

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.38.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.38.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1t zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.29 libssh2/1.4.3 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

Any idea how I can get curl to work with SSL proxy enabled on the server?

Comment: Have you tried running curl with the `-x` option? Or failing to get things working otherwise, the `-k` option?

Comment: I have tried the -k and it still generates the same error. I'm not sure how ti use the -x option

Comment: To get more information, you might try: `curl -k -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer xyz' https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me`.  In that _verbose_ output, right after the "Connected to ..." message, there should be information about the SSL certificate.  Hopefully those messages provide more context for the issue you're encountering.